# unexpected errors on multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm new to multiprocessing. When I run the code below, some error occurs which vary every time.
Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
mesh_num=256
mean=[0,0]
cov=[[10,0],[0,20]]
position=np.random.multivariate_normal (mean,cov,size=4)
x_range=np.linspace(np.min(position[:,0]),np.max(position[:,0]),mesh_num)
y_range=np.linspace(np.min(position[:,1]),np.max(position[:,1]),mesh_num)
x_step=x_range[1]-x_range[0]
y_step=y_range[1]-y_range[0]
x_range=np.linspace(np.min(position[:,0])-x_step,np.max(position[:,0])+x_step,mesh_num)
y_range=np.linspace(np.min(position[:,1])-y_step,np.max(position[:,1])+y_step,mesh_num)
x_step=x_range[1]-x_range[0]
y_step=y_range[1]-y_range[0]

charge_density=mp.Array('d',np.zeros(mesh_num*mesh_num))
position=position.tolist()
def distribute(position):
    column_index_left=int(abs(position[0]-x_range[0])/x_step)
    column_index_right=column_index_left+1
    row_index_up=int(abs(position[1]-y_range[0])/y_step)
    row_index_down=row_index_up+1
    print(position[0])
    print(position[1])
    print(x_range)
    print(y_range)
    print(column_index_left)
    print(column_index_right)
    print(row_index_up)
    print(row_index_down)
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mp.Pool()
    pool.map(distribute,position)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I found the x_range and y_range are different from these two in the function  'distribute'. This confuses me. I think they should be the same.
How to fix the problem?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: What are the errors (post the full stack trace showing the errors), or how is the behavior deviating from your expectations?

Comment: index 257(this number varies every time I run the code) is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 256 or invalid index

Comment: Could you please run my code on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot duplicate an index out of bounds issue. Frankly, my head is spinning trying to follow your logic. But is clearly another problem:

'+=' is not an atomic operation, so if there is any chance of two tasks attempting to update the same index, you need to explicitly treat this operation as a *critical section*, for example:

```py
    with charge_density.get_lock():
        charge_density[mesh_num*row_index_up+column_index_left]+=(1-abs(x_range[column_index_left]-position[0])/x_step)*(1-abs(y_range[row_index_up]-position[1])/y_step)
```

You can hold the lock for all 4 '+=' operations or release and re-acquire the lock for successive operations. If there is no possibility of parallel tasks updating the same index, then your code will run faster by creating a `RawArray` instead of an `Array`.

Also, you say "Could you please run my code on your computer?". This code can only run on a computer that uses *fork* to create new processes, such as Linux. On Windows, for example, which uses *spawn*, every process in the multiprocessing pool would be creating its own instance of the shared memory Array. That would not be very sharable, would it? To be portable, the code would need to be re-organized as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp


def init_pool_processes(*args):
    global mesh_num, mean, cov, position, x_range, y_range, x_step, y_step, x_range, y_range, x_step, y_step, charge_density
    mesh_num, mean, cov, position, x_range, y_range, x_step, y_step, x_range, y_range, x_step, y_step, charge_density = args

def distribute(position):
    column_index_left = int(abs(position[0] - x_range[0])/x_step)
    column_index_right = column_index_left + 1
    row_index_up = int(abs(position[1] - y_range[0])/y_step)
    row_index_down = row_index_up + 1
    with charge_density.get_lock():
        charge_density[mesh_num*row_index_up + column_index_left] += (1 - abs(x_range[column_index_left] - position[0])/x_step)*(1 - abs(y_range[row_index_up] - position[1])/y_step)
        charge_density[mesh_num*row_index_up + column_index_right] += (1 - abs(x_range[column_index_right] - position[0])/x_step)*(1 - abs(y_range[row_index_up] - position[1])/y_step)
        charge_density[mesh_num*row_index_down + column_index_left] += (1 - abs(x_range[column_index_left] - position[0])/x_step)*(1 - abs(y_range[row_index_down] - position[1])/y_step)
        charge_density[mesh_num*row_index_down + column_index_right] += (1 - abs(x_range[column_index_right] - position[0])/x_step)*(1 - abs(y_range[row_index_down] - position[1])/y_step)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mesh_num = 256
    mean = [0, 0]
    cov = [[10,0], [0,20]]
    position = np.random.multivariate_normal (mean, cov, size=100000)
    x_range = np.linspace(np.min(position[:,0]), np.max(position[:,0]), mesh_num)
    y_range = np.linspace(np.min(position[:,1]), np.max(position[:,1]), mesh_num)
    x_step = x_range[1] - x_range[0]
    y_step = y_range[1] - y_range[0]
    x_range = np.linspace(np.min(position[:,0]) - x_step,np.max(position[:,0]) + x_step, mesh_num)
    y_range = np.linspace(np.min(position[:,1]) - y_step,np.max(position[:,1]) + y_step, mesh_num)
    x_step = x_range[1] - x_range[0]
    y_step = y_range[1] - y_range[0]
    charge_density = mp.Array('d', np.zeros(mesh_num*mesh_num))

    pool = mp.Pool(initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(
        mesh_num,
        mean,
        cov,
        position,
        x_range,
        y_range,
        x_step,
        y_step,
        x_range,
        y_range,
        x_step,
        y_step,
        charge_density
        )
    )

    pool.map(distribute, position)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I have also tried to introduce a few of the suggestions from the [PEP 8 – Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/). When you have a chance, take a look at it.